# Unable to print out shape of my tensor (Keras)

Tags: python, keras

Very new to Keras and I am running into an issue when I am trying to print out the shape so I can use this as the input_shape. Here is my code so far:

```
df = pd.read_csv(pathname, encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
df = df[['content_cleaned', 'meaningful']] 
df = df.sample(frac=1) #Shuffling the data

X = np.asarray(df[['content_cleaned']])
y = np.asarray(df[['meaningful']])

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=21) 

tokenizer = Tokenizer() 
X_train = keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer(num_words=100)
X_test = keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer(num_words=100)

encoder = LabelBinarizer()
encoder.fit(y_train) 
y_train = encoder.transform(y_train)
encoder.fit(y_test)
y_test = encoder.transform(y_test)

print(X_train.shape)
```

The code is failing at the final print statement. Error message:

```
AttributeError: 'Tokenizer' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Again, I am quite new to this and can't seem to figure out how to move past this error. Any help would be great!

Edit: I have made some modifications to the code, trying to implement what another user suggested. Here is the code (that has changed):

```
# Create tokenizer
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=100) #No row has more than 100 words.

#Tokenize the predictors (text)
X_train = tokenizer.sequences_to_matrix(X_train, mode="binary")
X_test = tokenizer.sequences_to_matrix(X_test, mode="binary")
```

It is failing when declaring X_train variable. Error message is:

```
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Edit 2: Making the following changes, the code does run. When I run the print command, nothing is printing:

```
X_train = tokenizer.sequences_to_matrix(int(input(X_train)), mode="binary")
X_test = tokenizer.sequences_to_matrix(int(input(X_test)), mode="binary")
```

Comment: `X_train = keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer(num_words=100)` and `X_test = keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer(num_words=100)` doesn't make sense. Your actual data in `X_train` and `X_test` is simply overwritten with the output of Tokenizer. You should instead create an object such as `obj1= keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer(num_words=100)`  and apply it to your `X_train` and `X_test`. Try reading some tutorials on how to use Tokenizer.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/text-classification-in-keras-part-2-how-to-use-the-keras-tokenizer-word-representations-fd571674df23)

Comment: @Bazingaa Just made an edit. I am getting another error when doing this. This was actually the guide I was referring to working on my code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because although you first set it as a numpy array...

`X = np.asarray(df[['content_cleaned']])`

... and feed it data...

`X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=21)`

... then, you make it a Tokenizer object, which apparently has no 'shape' attribute.

`X_train = keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer(num_words=100)`

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am a bit thrown off as it looks as if I need to know the input_shape when creating the layers. I was following an online guide so I can understand some of the logic. Any way to work around my solution? Am I going about this incorrectly?